# Specify L2TP VPN to use other port

Tags: security, vpn, firewall, l2tp

I am currently at a hotel and they seem to block VPN use. I assume they block it by looking into the port it uses.

I would like to use my company VPN (L2TP). So, I think my best bet is to change the port into something like 443 or 80. Is there any way to do this in Ubuntu?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Changing it on your end will not lead to functioning VPN unless your company also changes it on their end